# Part of Graphics disappears when sent to printer

Tags: java, printing, graphics2d

I am trying to print a table to a piece of paper in a custom style, but only the column headers are printed on the page when I send it to the printer.

When using the same code to print to a JPanel, it works just fine.

I have been debugging like a madman, but all I've found is that a different Graphics is used when writing to a printer, and that it calculates the widths of the strings slightly differently, somehow, though I can't see how that should have an impact on what gets written or not.

I have been able to confirm that all the code is run, though.

The code that draws the headers:

```
private void drawColumnHeaders(Graphics2D g, PageFormat pf)
{
    g.drawLine(columnWidths[0]-1, 0, columnWidths[0]-1, rowHeight);
    drawText(g, 1, columnHeader[1]);
    drawLineAround(g, 1);
    drawText(g, 2, columnHeader[2]);
    drawLineAround(g, 2);
    etc...
    ...
    g.translate(0, rowHeight);
}
```

The code that draws the rows:

```
private void drawRow(Graphics2D g, Konto konto, boolean kunAfstanden)
{
    ...
    drawAccountNo(g, konto, 1);
    etc...
    ...
    g.translate(0, rowHeight);
}

...

private void drawAccountNo(Graphics2D g, Account account, int columnNo)
{
    switch (account.getType())
    {
    case SUMACCOUNT: 
        drawLineBeneath(g, columnNo);
    default:
        drawText(g, columnNo, "" + account.getAccountNo());
        break;
    }
}
```

Utility methods:

```
private void drawText(Graphics2D g, int columnNo, String text)
{
    int startX = calculatePosition(columnNo);
    g.drawString(text, startX + lMargin, g.getFontMetrics().getAscent() + aMargin);
}

private void drawLineAround(Graphics2D g, int columnNo)
{
    int startX = calculatePosition(columnNo);
    drawLineBeneath(g, columnNo);
    g.drawLine(startX + columnWidths[columnNo], 0, startX + columnWidths[columnNo], rowHeight);
}

...

private int calculatePosition(int columnNo)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNo; i++)
    {
        result+= columnWidths[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

The code that controls the printing:

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics ga, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException
{
    ga.setFont(normalFont);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) ga;
    if (!writeToPrinter)
    {
        pf = standardPF;
    }
    int returnMessage = -1;
    int noOfRowsOnPage = 0;
    calculateColumnWidths(g, pf);
    //Calculates how many pages there will be:
    calculateNoOfPages(g, pf);

    if (pageIndex < noOfPages)
    {
        //Translates Graphics:
        prepareGraphics(g, pf);
        //The parts that do show up:
        drawHeader(g, pf);
        drawStart(g, pf);
        drawColumnHeaders(g, pf);
        while (returnMessage == -1)
        {
            try
            {
                if (accounts.get(iReached).getType().t() != TypeAccount.NEWPAGE.t() && possibleRows > noOfRowsOnPage)
                {
                    //The part that doesn't (even though the code is reached):
                    drawRow(g, accounts.get(iReached));
                    noOfRowsOnPage++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //If the page isn't empty, go to the next page
                    if (noOfRowsOnPage > 0)
                    {
                        returnMessage = PAGE_EXISTS;
                    }
                }
                iReached++;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                returnMessage = PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        }
        drawFooter(g, pf, false);
    }
    else
    {
        returnMessage = NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
    return returnMessage;
}
```

The initialization of the PageFormat used:

```
standardPF = new PageFormat();
standardPF.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setImageableArea(30, 30, 535, 780);
paper.setSize(595.44, 841.68);
standardPF.setPaper(paper);
```

Comment: Perhaps the code that actually calls `drawRow` is the problem.  Also, are you using the PageFormat object to perform any different logic?

Comment: @VGR The code has been added.
I use a custom PageFormat object, with a custom page, but it's not used outside of what you see here. I'll just go ahead and add the initialization of that as well.

Comment: I have now tried to add another page, and the accounts print nicely on the 2nd page. Which is strange.

Comment: The PageFormat is determined by the system’s printer drivers;  its purpose is to inform you of the area where you can reliably draw.  You should not be ignoring it and you should not be using your own PageFormat in place of it.

Comment: The code is there to make it possible to use the same code to write to the screen as to write to the printer.I've changed it to

`if (!writeToPrinter) {pf = standardPF;}` The problem persists.